# instantiating a webclient object in jython giving strange results

Tags: python, webclient, jython, htmlunit

I am trying to use java's WebClient jar within a jython script.

I am running a jython script like so:

```
jython -Dpython.path=/home/tipu/Dropbox/dev/proj/lib/* test.py
```

the contents of test.py:

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient as WebClient
def main():
   webclient = WebClient() # creating a new webclient object.

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "scraper.py", line 1, in ?
ImportError: no module named gargoylesoftware
```

This is the conents of the lib folder in the python.path directory:

```
commons-codec-1.4.jar          commons-lang-2.6.jar       htmlunit-2.9.jar          httpcore-4.1.2.jar   sac-1.3.jar           xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar  commons-logging-1.1.1.jar  htmlunit-core-js-2.9.jar  httpmime-4.1.2.jar   serializer-2.7.1.jar  xml-apis-1.3.04.jar
commons-io-2.0.1.jar           cssparser-0.9.5.jar        httpclient-4.1.2.jar      nekohtml-1.9.15.jar  xalan-2.7.1.jar
```

Any idea as to why it isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think wildcards work when setting a system property like `python.path`. Try this:

> $ CLASSPATH=/home/tipu/Dropbox/dev/proj/lib/*
>
> $ jython test.py

Comment: Does it work if you use `export CLASSPATH=/home/tipu/Dropbox/dev/proj/lib/*` (bash), or `setenv CLASSPATH /home/tipu/Dropbox/dev/proj/lib/*` (csh)?

Comment: CLASSPATH="~/Dropbox/dev/proj/lib/*"

Comment: So you need double quotes? For me it works with `export CLASSPATH=...` (without quotes). This is on Linux with bash. What OS and shell do you use?

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do is adding the .jar files to java's classpath. This is the location where java looks for modules/classes to be imported.
In Mac OS:
open up a terminal, and enter:

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/x/y/htmlunit-2.11/lib/*
```

where /x/y/htmlunit-2.11/lib/ is the directory where all the .jar files are located.