# Jython ImportError: No module named gargoylesoftware, no resolution found

Tags: java, python, web-scraping, jython, htmlunit

I would like to use jython for basic web scraping task rather than learning java. To learn the basics I'm using an example from http://blog.databigbang.com/web-scraping-ajax-and-javascript-sites/ I've been unsuccessfully trying to run the gartner.py code from Windows cmd. Could anyone suggest a resolution to why both

```
jython -J-classpath "path\to\the\jars\*" path\to\gartner.py
```

and

```
jython path\to\gartner.py
```

keep on throwing out

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path\to\gartner.py", line 1, in <module>
    import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient as WebClient
ImportError: No module named gargoylesoftware
```

given I've got environment variables set up for jython `path\to\jython\bin`, for java `path\to\Java\jdk-14.0.1\bin` and for the htmlunit-2.40.0 I've added `path\to\jars\htmlunit-2.40.0\lib` to the CLASSPATH. 
I understand that jython should pick up the specified package in `jython -J-classpath "path\to\the\jars\*" path\to\gartner.py` but it does not find it. Also, I understand that in the case of `jython path\to\gartner.py` the defined CLASSPATH variable is available to Java pointing at htmlunit-2.40.0 (as mentioned above) whilst jython serves only as a translator from python to java. So - in my understanding - java shouild have all parameters available to import the desired module. Please, could anyone confirm?

I appreciate this subject has been somewhat discussed but there is no clear resolution available. What could I be missing?

Comment: looks like duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774498/instantiating-a-webclient-object-in-jython-giving-strange-results

Answer (score 0):

The error looks very clearly like you're missing a Java dependency. The jython issue with this specific library has already been discussed in a different thread: [instantiating a webclient object in jython giving strange results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774498/instantiating-a-webclient-object-in-jython-giving-strange-results)

Comment: Ok, thank you. For reference, in my case the reason it was failing was the lack of \'*' at the end of the library classpath. As expected, it did not matter whether the classpath is defined as an environment variable or overriden in the runtime as might have been inferred from other similar threads